# Will the XBOX One Controller work work with my Bluetooth Mouse dongle?

Tags: pc, bluetooth, video-game-console

I have a Bluetooth mouse "**Terabyte 100031N Ultra Slim Wireless Mouse (Black)**" and was planning to buy a XBOX one controller for my PC.

Was wondering if the controller needs specific Bluetooth dongle or will a generic Bluetooth dongle of my mouse work with the controller.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a ... "Terabyte 100031N Ultra Slim Wireless Mouse (Black)"

[This mouse](https://www.amazon.in/Terabyte-Ultra-Wireless-Mouse-BLACK/dp/B07BK5T43Z) does not use [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) at all. It is simply a "wireless" mouse that uses some sort of proprietary 2.4 Ghz signal to communicate with its USB dongle. That means **you can not connect any Bluetooth device to the dongle for that mouse**. It is unlikely that you can even use that dongle for another mouse of the exact same model!

> Was wondering if the controller needs specific Bluetooth dongle?

The Xbox One controller supports either the [proprietary USB adapter](https://www.xbox.com/en-CA/xbox-one/accessories/adapters/wireless-adapter-windows) (for all wireless controllers), or some newer controller models support Bluetooh 4.0. Bluetooth is a *wireless communication standard*, so that means *any* Bluetooth 4.0 dongle will work for those controllers.

Only the Xbox One S controllers can connect to a Bluetooth dongle. [Here is a guide](https://www.pcgamer.com/xbox-one-controller-on-pc/#how-to-connect-the-xbox-one-controller-via-bluetooth-xa0) to help you identify if you have the correct type of controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will be able to. Mouse and keyboard receivers tend to come paired to the device in question. Or they may offer a way to pair a device, but there is nothing to say that this will be able to pair to another device.

You can try to check if you can pair anything to it by checking your computers Bluetooth settings to see if it detects a Bluetooth receiver.

If this isn't the case, a quick check on Amazon shows Bluetooth receivers for around £5. I have used a cheap Bluetooth receiver for many years for Xbox controllers and headphones without issue.